# Bracket auto close in JSX/HTML component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, visual-studio-code

When I input the `{` in the middle of any JSX/HTML component, the `VSCode` is not closing it - have you got any ideas how to configure settings or is there any extension for auto-close?

Example:

```
const MathButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button>{</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in this thread? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127739

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `settings.json` in `VS Code`:

> "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"

or

Go to:

*File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Auto closing Brackets*
Change it to `always`

[image: Auto Closing Brackets]